GRASS plugin r.stream.snap breaks database linking - how to restore it?
r.stream.snap generates a vector with two layers. In the first, as mentioned in the documentation, the input categories are preserved. I get a vector map without any connection to the database.
I have my input file with points, names, additional information and cats. When I try to v.db.connect map=snapped_points table=old_points, it writes that the old_points table doesn't exist but connects it. After that, this table with old points is corrupted.
What is the right way to connect the old table to snapped points?
UPD: I've found it to be a bug so my question is "How  I can link a layer to this product of r.stream.snap manually and from command line
UPD2: My version about $MAPSET variable was wrong, it still doesn't work, although $MAPSET is reset to PERMANENT correctly.
Here is the text of errors. It says that table doesn,t exist while it was newly created with v.in.ogr before that.
WARNING: Table <gages> does not exist in database    
</output/GRASSDATA/my_dbase/my_location/PERMANENT/sqlite/sqlite.db>
The table <gages> is now part of vector map <corr_gages> and may be 
deleted
or overwritten by GRASS modules
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Unable to create index:
create unique index if not exists gages_cat on gages ( cat )
no such table: main.gages

DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Unable to create index:
create unique index if not exists gages_cat on gages ( cat )
no such table: main.gages

WARNING: Cannot create index
Select privileges were granted on the table

UPD3: My research has shown that gages table disappears exactly after r.stream.snap has been done.
My command is:
r.stream.snap input=gages stream_rast=streams threshold=500000 
radius=30 output=corr_gages --overwrite

UPD4: Temporal solution seems to be found:
g.copy vector=old,old_bkup
r.stream.snap input=old [...] output=new
v.db.addtable map=new
v.db.join map=new column=cat other_table=old_bkup other_column=cat


I proposed a bug https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/issues/4793

The problem was in absence of $MAPSET variable. A default database=$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db. My $MAPSET was NULL, so GRASS didn't know where was the database.
All is correct if I write PERMANENT in place of $MAPSET.
If I add $MAPSET variable the command enough to connect this table would be: v.db.connect map=corr_gages table=old_gages

Unfortunately, the error still stays.
